# What is a constant address space qualifier in OpenCL?

Tags: c, opencl, osx-yosemite

I'm trying  to run the noise OpenCL sample project included in the XCode documentation.

I have one error that I don't understand:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Using active OpenGL context...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Connecting to NVIDIA GeForce 320M...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading kernel source from file 'noise_kernel.cl'...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Building compute program...
[CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE] : OpenCL Error : Error: Build Program driver returned (10007)
Break on OpenCLErrorBreak to debug.
OpenCL Warning : clBuildProgram failed: could not build program for 0x1022600 (GeForce 320M) (err:-2)
Break on OpenCLWarningBreak to debug.
[CL_BUILD_ERROR] : OpenCL Build Error : Compiler build log:
<program source>:58:21: error: global variables must have a constant address space qualifier
static const float4 ZERO_F4 = (float4)(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

There is an error on this last line, which involves a const variable. How do you interpret this ? It looks like the compiler is rejecting ZERO_F4 because it's not const, but as you can see, it actually is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It looks like the compiler is rejecting ZERO_F4 because it's not
> const, but as you can see, it actually is.

The compiler is rejecting it because `ZERO_F4` is not in `__constant` address space (this has nothing to do with `const`). I believe it's a bug in the XCode samples, because the OpenCL C spec clearly says:

> **Section 6.5 Address space qualifiers:**
>
> All program scope variables must be declared in the `__constant` address space.

Therefore replace this:

```
static const float4 ZERO_F4 = (float4){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
static const float4 ONE_F4  = (float4){ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
```

With this:

```
__constant float4 ZERO_F4 = (float4){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
__constant float4 ONE_F4  = (float4){ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
```

And it should work.

Comment: Has there been some changes on the compilers that break the previous (supposedly working ?) code ? I'm currently fixing another code sample with the same problem (Grass..)

Comment: I suppose it's a bug that may have been fixed since the samples have been written, yes. The spec itself has always stated that global-scope variables must be `__constant`.